# Find the Count of Consecutive Occurrence in Table using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016, aggregation, gaps-and-islands

enter code here have a table like this in my SQl Server

```
  NTN        |   Channel          Date_Time
006175A      |   Yellow         15-9-2021 10:16:00:00
0061751      |   Green          15-9-2021 10:15:00:00
00617523     |   Red            15-9-2021 10:14:00:00
006175A      |   Green          15-9-2021 10:13:00:00
006175A      |   Green          15-9-2021 10:12:00:00
006175A      |   Green          15-9-2021 10:11:00:00
0061756      |   Red            15-9-2021 10:10:00:00
00617523     |   Green          16-9-2021 10:10:00:00
00617523     |   Green          16-9-2021 10:12:00:00
```

Now what I am trying to do is to display consecutive Green for my NTN column like this:

```
 NTN        |    Greens |  Max(Date_Time)          |   Min(Date_Time)
 006175A    |     3     |  15-9-2021 10:13:00:000  |   15-9-2021 10:11:00:00
 00617523   |     2     |  16-9-2021 10:12:00:000  |   16-9-2021 10:10:00:00
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this using SQL Server

Comment: Why doesn't NTN=0061751 appear in your expected results, with a longest sequence of 1?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but the key phrase to search for on Google that will help you is "gaps and islands".

Comment: Why does your datetime go down in minutes, but then up in days?

Comment: Where you have three Greens in a row, if a Red occurred in the middle, but for a different NTN, would that change the expected result?

Comment: @MatBailie yes it would change the expected result as i want consecutive greens of same NTN.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (    ORDER BY date_time
                      )
                        AS seq_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ntn, channel
                           ORDER BY date_time
                      )
                        AS ntn_channel_seq_id
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  ntn,
  COUNT(*),
  MIN(date_time),
  MAX(date_time)
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
  channel = 'Green'
GROUP BY
  ntn,
  seq_id - ntn_channel_seq_id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
  ntn,
  seq_id - ntn_channel_seq_id
```

De mo with a series of slightly differing test sets:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=00229ee69f6962b3f7ed8cdfe9d39d56

Comment: Ya beat me to it on the "Difference between two sequences" thing.  I was busy adding other stuff for the OP.  Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . The last greens meet this condition:  There are no-nongreens after the row and before the last green row.  You can do this using window functions:

```
select ntn, count(*) as last_greens, min(date_time), max(date_Time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when channel <> 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ntn order by date_time desc) as non_greens_after
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when channel = 'Green' then date_time end) over (partition by ntn order by date_time) as max_green_dt
            from t
           ) t
      where date_time <= max_green_dt
     ) t
where non_greens_after = 0 and channel = 'Green'
group by ntn;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65b693235ddf0c45214845ce5548dc68) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  You do not explain why `'0061751'` is not included.  If you want at least two greens, then include `having count(*) >= 2`.

Comment: There is a non green after the last green row in my actual data.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I get the following error when running your code if the table is named "t":  Column 't.NTN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score -1):

@humair-hassan ,

First, help others help you in the future by posting "Readily Consumable Data" in the form of code that someone can just run to create and populate a table with your test data.  You'll get more and better answers much more quickly.

Here's one way of doing that for the test data you posted.  Note that it's generally better to do it in the form of a Temp Table so that the data persists, which is easier to write test code against.

```
--===== Set the date format to match the format of the given test data.
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY
;
--===== Create the data as a readily consumable table.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
 SELECT  NTN       = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),v.NTN)
        ,Channel   = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),v.Channel)
        ,Date_Time = CONVERT(DATETIME   ,v.Date_Time)
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM (VALUES
         ('006175A' ,'Yellow','15-9-2021 10:16:00:00')
        ,('0061751' ,'Green' ,'15-9-2021 10:15:00:00')
        ,('00617523','Red'   ,'15-9-2021 10:14:00:00')
        ,('006175A' ,'Green' ,'15-9-2021 10:13:00:00')
        ,('006175A' ,'Green' ,'15-9-2021 10:12:00:00')
        ,('006175A' ,'Green' ,'15-9-2021 10:11:00:00')
        ,('0061756' ,'Red'   ,'15-9-2021 10:10:00:00')
        ,('00617523','Green' ,'16-9-2021 10:10:00:00')
        ,('00617523','Green' ,'16-9-2021 10:12:00:00')
        )v(NTN,Channel,Date_Time)
;
```

[EDIT]
@MatBailie pointed out a flaw I had in my code and I've taken it down so that no one makes the mistake of using it.

I also checked the code he submitted and his is spot on.

I left the test data creation script in case someone else wanted to have a go at it.

Comment: This puts all occurences of Green in to the same group, for each `ntn` (it shouldn't). The OP needs sequential occurences of Green and the same `ntn` only, occounting for 'interruptions' even by values from other `ntn`s, etc. See my fiddle with your code, and compare the results; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1b96ace113d159958189b2a78ed00498

Comment: Thanks.  You were right.  I've deleted my erroneous code so that no one would use it by mistake.